# & converted into &amp; when $_POST request is called?

Tags: php, android, apache, post

We are working on an application which has 2 modules.

1. Android Application.
2. PHP Application
   PHP backend application runs on an Apache Server with Centos Server.
   Android application basically clicks images, send to the server along with gps coordinates etc form information.

Now the problem arises when the image file is created on the server. When android app calls the url the '&' character is replaced by & amp;, sometimes even by & amp;& amp; and this problem repeats in some of the cases. Once this conversion thing happens, image file is not created properly.

How it can be resolved?

Same code was working alright from past year, this problem begin to arise from last month only....

Following is the code for saving the images at server end :

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { 
    $_POST[$x] = $value;
}

$base=$_REQUEST['image'];
$nm=$_REQUEST['name'];
$binary=base64_decode($base);


if(file_exists("uploaded_images/".$nm.".jpg")) {

unlink("uploaded_images/".$nm.".jpg");
}

header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
$str="uploaded_images/".$nm.".jpg";
$file = fopen($str, 'wb');
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);
chmod($file,0777);
$ok=1;
echo $ok;
```

Following is the error log which is encountered if image is not properly saved.
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /var/www/html/cbd/def/filesubmitnew.php
Note : filesubmitnew.php is the file name of the above code.

In Android Application for this is how the url is called:

To Create image:

```
if(buttontext.equals("Img1"))   {
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    v.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    buttontext="";
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, stream);
    byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
    String str1 = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
    System.out.println(""+str1);
    if(feuser.equals("offline_access")){
    System.out.println("++==--SD CARD");
    File externalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File folder = new File(externalStorage.getAbsolutePath() +mainFolder + caseId);
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
    }
    File pictureFile = new File(externalStorage.getAbsolutePath()+mainFolder+caseId, "1.jpg");
    System.out.println(pictureFile);
    pictureFile.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
    OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
    myOutWriter.append(str1);
    myOutWriter.close();
    fOut.close();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Done writing SD "+pictureFile,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else    {

    Intent i = new Intent ("com.keyboardlabs.newbankge.CameraUploadService");
    try {
        i.putExtra("imageparams", str1);
        i.putExtra("ref_id", caseId);
        i.putExtra("imageId", "1");
        i.putExtra("CaseType",caseType);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    getApplicationContext().startService(i);
}
```

Following is the camerauploadservice

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {

    String imageDataBase64encoded =  arg0.getStringExtra("imageparams");
String caseID = arg0.getStringExtra("ref_id");
String imageId = arg0.getStringExtra("imageId");
String caseType =arg0.getStringExtra("CaseType");
System.out.println("image_ref="+caseID+"iamgeID="+imageId+"caseType="+caseType+" URL="+URL);

callWebService(imageDataBase64encoded,caseID,imageId,caseType);
}

public void callWebService(String imageData,String refId,String imageId,String caseType){  

    HttpClient httpclient = null;

ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",imageData));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ref_id",refId));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imageId",imageId));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CaseType",caseType));
try{
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    String the_string_response = convertResponseToString(response);
    System.out.println( "Response= " + the_string_response);
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println( "0" + e.getMessage());
    System.out.println("Error in http connection "+e.toString());
}
httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();  
}
```

Comment: Have you tried url encoder, it would be better if share a sample url to us.

Comment: Your question needs a working example of a request posted to PHP without any Android code. Either that request does already contain the `&amp;` entity - then the Android code is to blame. Or it does not - only then it is your PHP code. But for sure it is something you added, because PHP does not automatically escape strings into entities.

Comment: @sven: Actually problem is not in php or android code as I was also running this same android application with c# & asp.net code in the backend on an IIS 7.0 server. Same problem occurs in IIS....hence Server hangs and we have to and our mobile application stops working. We have to restart it for app to work. But we resolved this problem in IIS by sending files via ftp connection. I am implementing same ftp functionality in php application also. Probably this will reslove the problem, but why it didn't work in POST request properly and the inconsistency of the problem is beyond me

Comment: Well, if the same app does not work with two server backends, I do pretty much think the app is broken, not the servers. You don't really want to use FTP as a workaround, the protocol is completely weird and will break on several occasions. For example, users will be behind proxies that allow HTTP but deny FTP.